# Python (pyenv) Compile error - missing OpenSSL on mac os x

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, openssl, macos-mojave

I am trying to install AWS EB-CLI on macOS Mojave 10.14, and encountered following error when compiling Python.

```
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?  

BUILD FAILED (OS X 10.14.5 using python-build 20180424)
```

In the pyenv wiki, it says,

1. install additional SDK headers – which I did
2. libssl-dev is required when compiling Python ....

Things I did so far...

- install OpenSSL via brew
- sym link above to /user/lib
- install xz  via brew (due to a 'lzma.h' file not found error)

Now the error is:

```
could not build the ssl module!
Python requires an OpenSSL 1.0.2 or 1.1 compatible libssl with X509_VERIFY_PARAM_set1_host().
LibreSSL 2.6.4 and earlier do not provide the necessary APIs, https://github.com/libressl-portable/portable/issues/381
```

I am migrating to Mac from Windows and having a hard time understanding this.
Any help would be much appreciated.

---

*Eric solved his problem and posted an answer for this question. I am moving the inquiry he appended to his answer onto his question*:

> now need to look what was actual culprit? do i really need xz etc. any ideas?

I think he is asking -- [as are 39 others on the issue he linked to](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1184) as of 2020-DEC-18 01:34am UTC -- what the root cause is, and what the solution is?

The issue is still open. Some common themes:

- fish shell - various issues
- openssl - not installed? (unlikely)
- openssl - version 1.0.2o_2 installed; some fixed by installing openssl@1.1
- pkg-config - not installed, potentially due to source install instead of homebrew
- pkg-config - wrong version being pulled from path first.

Some useful comments on the issue:

- User attempting the openssl@1.1 fix provides helpful [output from homebrew](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1184#issuecomment-582072507) regarding path and env var settings necessary for openssl and pkg-config.

  - An [issue linked to in response to the above comment](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1425#issue-507927539) has some [very useful information](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1425#issuecomment-543792585) that helped a few users solve their issue.
- Debian user, but ["LD_RUN_PATH is a necessary option"](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1184#issuecomment-430427434)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the answer.

`CONFIGURE_OPTS="--with-openssl=$(brew --prefix openssl)"`

did the trick

more info @ https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1184

Comment: You answered your own question and didn't accept it? Bump!